# Salesforce Flow History Tracking

Tags: visual-workflow

I have a flow in Salesforce that has made changes to records in my organization. I would like to identify which records were affected by the flow. How can I track and determine the specific records impacted by the flow, considering that I have temporarily deactivated the flow?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Flow simply does DML on records and any changes to those records would be in the Field History tracking for those objects (assuming you have History Tracking enabled and the fields affected by the Flow are tracked)

- However, this won't tell you that the Flow made the change as the running user is the user that initiated the transaction

What you can do is is have your Flow create Activity records to track what it does in conjunction with DML to records.

There are also custom Flow logging frameworks such as this [UnofficialSF.com one](https://unofficialsf.com/custom-logging-in-flows/). Google to locate others that meet your needs

Answer (score 0):

To expand on @cropredy 's response, a record triggered flow will run as the user who initiated the change, meaning there is not a distinct identifier that a particular record was modified by any particular flow.

I presume there was some sort of flow error/update/miscalculation that you are hoping to observe and fix. If you have been able to fix the flow, I would recommend using it to fix you data.

1. If records would still fit entry criteria, you could upload a "blank" update on all the records that have been updated in the past x days. You can do this by uploading an Insert through a data load tool such as Inspector with only the record Ids.
2. If they do not fit entry criteria you could use a new checkbox to force re-entry to the flow by adding it to the entry criteria logic, i.e. (1 AND 2 AND 3) OR 4, 4 being the new "Force Recalculate" checkbox = true.

To avoid this happening in future flow updates, you can have a field on key objects that display the "Last Update by Flow Name" with the name of the flow stamped whenever it runs. Tracking this field would show the history of flow updates upon it.